# Question regarding a unitary matrix $V$ containing an eigenvector $v$ of $A$ as its first column

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A\in \mathbb{M}^{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$.  Let $(\lambda,v)$ an
>   eigenpair of $A$ and $\|v\|=1$.  Let $V$ be a unitary matrix with $v$
>   as first column. Prove that there exists a $b \in \mathbb{C}^{n-1}$
>   and $B\in \mathbb{M}^{(n-1)\times (n-1)}$
>
> $$ AV=V\left( \begin{array}{c|c}   \lambda & b^* \\ \hline   0 &
>  {{\mbox{$B$}}} \\   \vdots & \\  0 & \end{array}
>  \right) $$

It's quite some time ago that I followed my first linear algebra course.  I forget how I can see such an equality. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I've edited the title. Feel free to change it to something that reflects the content better, but please don't put a huge matrix in the title.

Comment: This simply says that there exists an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ starting with $v$. This does not require anything but the existence of an orthonormal basis on $v^\perp$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(v,e_2,\cdots,e_n)$ a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and by [Gram–Schmidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) we can orthonormalise this basis $(v,e_2,\cdots,e_n)$ in a basis $\mathcal{B}=(v,v_2,\cdots,v_n)$ and then the matrix $A$ is similar to the matrix 
$$\left( \begin{array}{c|c}   \lambda & b^* \\ \hline   0 &
 {{\mbox{$B$}}} \\   \vdots & \\  0 & \end{array}
 \right) $$
written in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ and the change matrix from the canonical basis to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ is the unitary matrix $V=(v,v_2,\cdots,v_n)$.